# Design - Interaction of multiple coupled subclasses

Tags: oop

Starting simple, I have two objects -- a Player and a Game:

```
Game, Player
```

The Player sends its moves to the Game which processes them and updates the state of the Player (along with all other Players in the Game):

```
Player.do_move_X:
    game.handle_move_X()

Game.handle_move_X:
    player.take_damage(10)
```

Next, I add multiple Game types (subclasses of Game):

```
GameNormal, GameCaptureTheFlag, GamePractice
```

It's easy to change the behavior between different Game classes by simply re-implementing relevant methods in the subclass:

```
GamePractice.handle_move_X:
    player.take_damage(5)
```

Next, I add multiple Player subclasses:

```
PlayerNormal, PlayerUnregistered, PlayerElite
```

Now it's getting tricky because the interaction between a Player and Game depends both on the Player's type AND on the Game's type. Now I end up with code looking like this:

```
GamePractice.handle_move_X:
    if player is a PlayerNormal:
        player.take_damage(5)
    else if player is a PlayerUnregistered:
        player.take_damage(5)
    else if player is a PlayerElite:
        player.take_damage(10)
```

(Analogously, I could place that sort of logic in the Player classes instead of the Game classes.)

Checking the type of the objects in a big switch or if-else statement is ugly. One option I have is to add explicit methods to the Player class to handle a particular case for each Game type:

```
GameNormal.handle_move_X:
    player.take_normal_damage()

PlayerNormal.take_normal_damage:
    take_damage(10)

PlayerElite.take_normal_damage:
    take_damage(15)

GamePractice.handle_move_X:
    player.take_practice_damage()

PlayerNormal.take_practice_damage:
    take_damage(5)

PlayerElite.take_practice_damage:
    take_damage(10)
```

This eliminates the ugliness from above but adds a new ugliness -- it bloats the Player classes with public methods to handle each case for each Game type.

Is there any better paradigm or design for dealing with this sort of case?

Comment: How many instances of `Game` and `Player` (or any of their subclasses) may exist at the same time?

Comment: There are typically far more Players than there are Games. Each Game could have up to 256 Players.

Comment: Ok I just wanted to know if some of those were unique. Also what is your language? I know it is a general design problem, but things like pattern matching or visitor pattern depend on the language.

Comment: I don't want to bias the language as this is language-agnostic, but let's say C++. And just to clarify, each Player is only involved in 1 Game at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best possible approach, but I think that the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) could help here. The implementation depends on the language, but basically you have a `Visitor` interface with a `visit` method for `Player` and every subclass of it. Then, for every class in the `Player` tree, you would an `accept` method, or maybe just for the subclasses, if `Player` is interface/abstract:

```
PlayerNormal.accept(Visitor v):
    v.visit(this)

PlayerUnregistered.accept(Visitor v):
    v.visit(this)

PlayerElite.accept(Visitor v):
    v.visit(this)
```

Finally, you would need an implementation of `Visitor` for `Game` and every subclass of it - again, maybe just for the subclasses. This could be a private class:

```
GameNormal.TakeDamageVisitor.visit(PlayerNormal p):
    p.take_damage(10)
GameNormal.TakeDamageVisitor.visit(PlayerUnregistered p):
    p.take_damage(10)
GameNormal.TakeDamageVisitor.visit(PlayerElite p):
    p.take_damage(15)

GameCaptureTheFlag.TakeDamageVisitor.visit(PlayerNormal p):
    p.take_damage(10)
GameCaptureTheFlag.TakeDamageVisitor.visit(PlayerUnregistered p):
    p.take_damage(15)
GameCaptureTheFlag.TakeDamageVisitor.visit(PlayerElite p):
    p.take_damage(15)

GamePractice.TakeDamageVisitor.visit(PlayerNormal p):
    p.take_damage(5)
GamePractice.TakeDamageVisitor.visit(PlayerUnregistered p):
    p.take_damage(5)
GamePractice.TakeDamageVisitor.visit(PlayerElite p):
    p.take_damage(10)
```

Finally, you could have each `Game` subclass return an instance of its own kind of `Visitor` in a `get_take_damage_visitor` method, and, if you store a reference to the game in each player, you can do:

```
Player.do_move_X:
    accept(game.get_take_damage_visitor)
```

Pros:

- You don't need switchs or if-elseif constructs, and there are no downcasts.
- In compiled languages, you get a compilation error if you forget to add some case.
- You can define other visitors for similar problems.

Cons:

- The logic may be somewhat confusing at first, although it is a well-established design pattern.
- It may be a hassle to maintain if you have many subtypes of `Player` and/or `Game` - although this may hold for any possible alternative, and at least here the compiler helps you.

Lastly, depending on the language, you can implement a similar idea more easily if you have [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) (actually, the visitor pattern is kind of a trick to implement something like multiple dispatch in languages without it), or in C++ with a templated function.